# I'm trying to reproduce the result of a post, my training acc is better though my test acc is very bad, how do I do?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to reproduce the result of [this post](https://www.kaggle.com/louisong97/neural-network-approach-to-iris-dataset)

I'm using tensorflow 2.5.0, so this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

gives

```
2.5.0
```

I imported the packages as that post did

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
```

The construction of training and test set is a bit different from the way in that post though, I don't think this matters.

```
iris = load_iris()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.33, random_state=2021)
```

I normalized the data as that post did

```
x_train=normalize(x_train,axis=0)
y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(y_train,num_classes=3)
y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,num_classes=3)
```

Here is the model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, input_dim=4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train,y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), batch_size=20,epochs=20,verbose=0)
```

my accuracy on training set is a bit higher

```
prediction=model.predict(x_train)
length=len(prediction)
y_label=np.argmax(y_train,axis=1)
predict_label=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)   
accuracy=np.sum(y_label==predict_label)/length * 100 
print("Accuracy of the dataset",accuracy )
```

and I got

```
Accuracy of the dataset 98.0
```

unfortunately, my accuracy on test set is way lower than that post

```
prediction=model.predict(x_test)
length=len(prediction)
y_label=np.argmax(y_test,axis=1)
predict_label=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)
accuracy=np.sum(y_label==predict_label)/length * 100 
print("Accuracy of the dataset",accuracy )
```

This is what I got

```
Accuracy of the dataset 28.000000000000004
```

Why is that?

updated:

with @HakanAkgün's suggestion, I normalized the test set and got 68 acc. The post I referenced gets 100%, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you normalize your train set but not the test set.
Before making predictions with the test set you should use:

```
x_test=normalize(x_test,axis=0)
```

[image]

And you'll have a more reasonable result.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion is very helpful. I normalized test set and got 68 acc. The post I referenced gets 100%, any other suggestions?

Comment: You can augment data with tf.keras.preprocessing.ImageDataGenerator (Adding noise, etc.). You can do hyperparameter tuning. You can use pre-trained models. Basically, there are number of ways to do that. I've just pointed out the main problem. Hope this helps.